# Как удалить неиспользуемые стили из CSS?

Tags: html, css

Имеется HTML и CSS файл, в котором много неиспользуемых стилей CSS которые хотелось бы удалить в автоматическом режиме и оставить только те стили, которые используются.
Как и чем это сделать?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Используйте **uncss**:

[gulp-uncss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uncss),

[npm uncss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncss)

А для сборки, нужно скачать и установить [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/), в проекте создать файлы: **package.json**, **gulpfile.js**.

**Минимальное содержимое package.json:**

`{ }`

В командной строке (*лучше бы coneEmu консоль*) выполнить установку **gulp** 

`npm install -g gulp`


`npm install --save-dev gulp`

Установить **gulp-uncss**: 

`npm install --save-dev gulp-uncss`

Настроить проект в **gulpfile.js** (*посмотреть в описании gulp-uncss + примеров в сети полно*).

**Минимальный gulpfile.js**:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uncss = require('gulp-uncss');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    return gulp.src('site.css')  // исходник
        .pipe(uncss({
            html: ['index.html', 'posts/**/*.html']
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./out')); // результат
});
```

... Это если коротко.

P.S: *Если нет времени, то тогда только руками удалять не нужные стили.*

Comment: Как ним воспользоваться? Я новичек, не знаю как это запустить.

Comment: @GuitarFan, Вам стоит посмотреть статьи о фронтенд сборке с помощью gulp. Например https://dmitriyilichev.com/sborka-front-end-proekta-s-pomoshhyu-gulp-i-node-js/. Есть и другие подробные статьи. Сейчас без gulp во фронтенде ни куда, поэтому рекомендую его освоить. Есть уроки у loft blog по gulp там вообще все подробно показано и рассказано как им пользоваться. А gulp-uncss - один из плагинов этого пакетного менеджера.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но мне пока некогда изучать много информации. Я хочу понять минимум того, чтобы я смог удалить лишние стили. Мне для этого нужно Скачать gulp и запустить этот gulp-uncss плагин в нем?

Comment: Если нет времени, то тогда только руками удалять не нужные стили.
А для сборки, нужно скачать и установить node.js, в проекте создать файлы: package.json (минимальное содержимое { ... } ), gulpfile.js.
В командной строке выполнить  установку gulp (npm install -g gulp, npm install --save-dev gulp), установить gulp-uncss (npm install --save-dev gulp-uncss). Настроить проект в gulpfile.js (посмотреть в описании gulp-uncss  + примеров в сети полно)...

Это если коротко.

Comment: @ElenaSemenchenko, перенесите описание в ответ

Comment: @HamSter, если нет времени, можно ведь пользоваться `uncss` [**из командной строки**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uncss#from-the-command-line), что быстрее, чем создавать конфигурацию в Grunt/Broccoli/Gulp. Спасибо.