# Плагин на gulp удаляющий неиспользуемые стили в css и неиспользуемые функции в js

Tags: javascript, gulp

Часто подключаю различные библиотеки (Bootstrap, JQuery), но использую из их функционала далеко не все. В итоге неиспользуемые стили и функции висят мертвым кодом и негативно сказываются на оптимизации. Знаю точно, есть плагин на gulp для css, который удаляет из файла неиспользуемые стили, но не помню, что это за плагин. И наверняка есть аналогичный плагин для js, чтобы удалять неиспользуемые функции, подскажите, кто знает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как удалить неиспользуемые стили из CSS?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560030/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d1%83%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-css)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский вопрос про JS, зачем помечать дубликатом вопрос о CSS?

Comment: для bootstrap есть [конструктор](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/), чтобы не скачивать лишнее

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko глянь в первоначальную версию вопроса

Comment: @АлексейШиманский ну заголовок был неоднозначный, но в самом вопросе вроде суть не поменялась.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko значит надо закрыть как "необходимо исправить, т.к. на него нельзя дать однозначно правильный ответ" :)

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko а вообще ТС еще клонировал вопрос... https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/734035/191482.... поэтому считаю что вообще отсюда можно js удалить и полноценно закрывать дублем по css.... а тот уже чисто по js