# Как с помощью gulp удалять неиспользуемые функции js

Tags: javascript, gulp

Я часто подключаю к своим проектам Jquery, но далеко не все функции из него использую, получается они висят мертвым кодом и портят оптимизацию. Какой плагин Gulp удалит из js неиспользуемые функции?

Comment: gulp-unused возможно

Comment: этот вопрос закрываем как дубликат предыдущего https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/733685/191482 ? или все же предыдущий будет по css а этот по js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минифактор вполне удалит все, что не используется в коде. Тот же uglify js (`gulp-uglify`).